# Firebase facebook button android authentication when logged out

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-authentication

I'm using firebase in my android app and facebook SDK for logging-in as well.
The only problem I'm facing is that when I log-in with facebook, then log-out, the facebook login button is in the "log-out" state and when I click it, it asks if I want to log-out.

like shown

[Problem ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tALV7.png)

What I do to log-out:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
```

so, this obviously only clears my session on firebase but doesn't disconnect my app with facebook, what to do?

Comment: you can use custom button without using facebook default button

Comment: Ok thanks @VishalPatoliya, I'll try it.

Comment: hi, can u help me please to add facebook firebase auth in my class pls? beacause have some problem. just look at code http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/629978/211117

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to log out from the Facebook SDK too, using the LoginManager class (com.facebook.login.LoginManager).

These two lines work for me:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

Hope this helps :)