# How to logout facebook account for entring another account

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, facebook-login, flutter-test

I am using flutter facebook auth.

When I login for the first time came to enter email and password after that I logout and went to login again then it did not ask for email and password.

When I login for the first time came to enter email and password after that I logout and went to login again then it did not ask for email and password.

and its looks like it
[image]

this is my facebook login functionality

```
import 'package:cwc/ApiManager/preference.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_facebook_auth/flutter_facebook_auth.dart';
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

// final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

String? fbName;
String? fbEmail;
String? fbImageUrl;

Future<String?> signInWithFacebook() async {
  // Trigger the sign-in flow
  final LoginResult loginResult = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();
  // final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
 var a= await loginResult.message;
  // Create a credential from the access token
  final OAuthCredential facebookAuthCredential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(loginResult.accessToken!.token);
  print("facebookAuthCredential22 ${facebookAuthCredential.token}");
  print("facebookAuthCredential33 ${facebookAuthCredential.accessToken}");
  print("facebookAuthCredential44 ${facebookAuthCredential.rawNonce}");
  // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
  final UserCredential authResult =
  await _auth.signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential);
  final User? users = authResult.user;
  final UserInfo? user = users!.providerData[0];
  print("facebookAuthCredential11 $user");
  // return FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential);

  if (user != null) {
    // Checking if email and name is null
    // assert(user.email != null);
    assert(user.displayName != null);
    assert(user.photoURL != null);

    Preferences.saveData("socialName", user.displayName.toString());
    Preferences.saveData("socialEmail", user.email.toString());
    Preferences.saveData("socialImage", user.photoURL.toString());

    // Only taking the first part of the name, i.e., First Name
    // if (googleName!.contains(" ")) {
    //   googleName = googleName!.substring(0, googleName!.indexOf(" "));
    // }

    assert(!users.isAnonymous);
    assert(await users.getIdToken() != null);

    final User? currentUser = _auth.currentUser;
    assert(users.uid == currentUser!.uid);

    print('signInWithFacebook succeeded: $user');

    return '$user';
  }

  return null;
}

Future<void> signOutWithFacebook() async {
  await FacebookAuth.instance.logOut();
  print("User Signed Out");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll also need to sign out of Facebook explicitly by calling:

```
FacebookAuth.instance.logOut()
```

Also see:

- [How to properly sign out of Facebook on Android with Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39434797/how-to-properly-sign-out-of-facebook-on-android-with-firebase)
- The documentation of `flutter_facebook_auth` on [signing out](https://facebook.meedu.app/docs/4.x.x/login#log-out)

Answer (score 0):

You can call the [`setCustomParameters()` method on `FacebookAuthProvider`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth_platform_interface/latest/firebase_auth_platform_interface/FacebookAuthProvider/setCustomParameters.html).

And pass the **consent** parameter like so:

```dart
_facebookAuth.setCustomParameters({"consent":"select_account"});
```

You can read about the parameters you can pass to the **consent** on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14393492/13725696)

Comment: As far as I can tell, this method only works with Web. I'll see to alternate solutions.